# How to get the list of application names and uninstall strings from JSON file and pass them as parameters to uninstall an application using powershell

Tags: json, powershell, windows-installer

I would like to read JSON file to get the list of application names and their respective uninstall strings and pass them as arguments in power shell to uninstall the apps irrespective of whether the apps are Windows Installer(MSI) or setup. Can someone please suggest me how to do this. Thanks

Comment: So your underlying question is, 'How do I read a JSON file'?

Comment: yes, also is it possible to pass those values in powershell as parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Use the ConvertFrom-JSON.
This will create a PSObject out of the JSON

```
$TEST2 = $TEST | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for suggesting the answer, that worked. I used the following cmd-line
$J = Get-Content -Raw -Path $scriptDirectory\Files\XXX.json | ConvertFrom-Json 
and passed the AppName property as given below to fetch the application names:
 $AppName = $J |fl -Property AppName.

FYI.. my JSON file content looked as follows:

[
     {
       "AppName": "xxxxx",
       "AppVersion": "aa.bb"
     },

```
 {
   "AppName": "yyy",
   "AppVersion": "aa.bb.cc"
 }
```

]